# How to turn on the capitals' circles on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps for a quiz that I've been making. I have turned labels and other stuff off from the map so that the person cannot see the names and choose the right country for the quiz. I want to make another level now that will have to do with capitals. So I would like to show on the map the little circles that google maps show right below the capital name,so that someone can click on it accurately, but I'm not sure what I should turn on to make them appear again. Any help appreciated!

This is the code for what I've turned off:

```
 var styles = [
  {
   featureType: "administrative",
               elementType: "labels",
               stylers: [
                 { visibility: "off" }
    ]
     },
 {
           featureType: "poi",
           elementType: "labels",
           stylers: [
             { visibility: "off" }
           ]
   }
 ,{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it..

```
  {
   featureType: "administrative.locality",
               elementType: "labels.icon",

               stylers: [
                 { visibility: "on" }
    ]
     }
```

The only thing is that it shows a lot of big cities not just capitals. If anyone knows a closer approach it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Playing with [the Styling Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)

Looks like adding this:

```
{ "featureType": "administrative.locality", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] }
```

Adds the little circles.  Doesn't look like there is any way to specify just capitols.  Perhaps you can just create a [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) or a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) with those points on it.  Here is an [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_AfricaMap_kml.html) using FusionTablesLayer with African capitols (and countries).

[Proof of concept FusionTables map that shows the capitols or the world](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1yV2xdwoCJYeKPy_5DyWYwaTd90wNh5tn3nX9_LE#map%3aid=3) (not verified)